# How do I use .FindControl in a Linq Query ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am just starting out with Linq to sql. I am struggling with passing control variables into the delete statement. Could someone take a look at this and point me in the right direction?

```
 protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();


    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked)
        {
           string prod_id = row.FindControl("lbl_id").ToString();

           Product product = (from p in db.Products 
                                  where p.ProductID == int.Parse(prod_id) // <-- I get conversion errors here!!
                                  select p).Single(); 

           db.Products.DeleteOnSubmit(product);

           db.SubmitChanges();


        }
    }

    ShowProducts();        
}
```

Comment: What is the exact conversion error?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Linq, it's only a distraction. Simplify your problem down to FindControl, ToString, and int.Parse.

Comment: Maybe you can detail what you're trying to do with FindControl in your context?

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: Maybe you meant `string prod_id = row.FindControl("lbl_id").Text.ToString();`?

Comment: I am trying to execute a delete statement using the the label value as the parameter.

Comment: How did this question get 3 down votes?????

Comment: @briskovich, if you moved `int.Parse` outside of the query, you would have seen Linq wasn't involved in the issue. If you had put a breakpoint on the line where you get the `prod_id` value, you would have known you didn't have a parseable integer, but rather a value such as "TextBox" or "Label." We give downvotes for not showing enough research effort (check the tooltip on the down arrow). Debugging your own program is research.

Comment: Okay I see. Fair enough. So I should have phrased the question something like " Converting string to integer throwing and exception?" Just want to know for the future.

Comment: In the future, you should follow those debugging techniques *before* asking, and then if you are satisfied that no further amount of research is going to produce an answer in a reasonable amount of time, then you have at least arrived at a more focused question. That question would *not* be "converting string to integer," because that road has been travelled and the answer is obvious. You didn't have an integer string. Your question (in this example) would be how to get the displayed value of whatever control you obtain via FindControl. (cont)

Comment: ..And even *that* probably shouldn't be asked, because on the immediately preceding line, you do precisely that with a different type of control! So the answer should start by following the same pattern. Cast it to the type, access the appropriate property. Done. No question necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem is there :

```
string prod_id = row.FindControl("lbl_id").ToString();
```

calling the ToString() method on a control will return the control type name, not the control value. You have to cast this control to whatever its type is, and then get the value in it. Let's suppose it's a textbox :

```
string prod_id = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("lbl_id")).Text;
```

Comment: Like a charm!! I knew I was close!! Awesome!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This line -

```
string prod_id = row.FindControl("lbl_id").ToString();
```

will return the control object type as the string. You should probably cast the return `Control` to the type of control you want, e.g.:

```
string prod_id = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("lbl_id")).Text;
```

As others stated, the problem is not with Linq but your treatment of the `FindControl` method.

So you can further understand what happened - suppose we use the `TextBox` control as above ...

```
   Product product = (from p in db.Products 
                      where p.ProductID == int.Parse(prod_id) // <-- I get conversion errors here!!
                      select p).Single();
```

With the current usage, `FindControl("lbl_id").ToString()` returns

> "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox"

Obviously, this will fail with `int.Parse(prod_id)`.

By changing the code to properly cast the control to the expected TextBox, then retrieve the Text property - e.g. "1", you can now parse the string "1" to the proper integer value.

This brings up the necessity to validate your input. At the very least, you should implement [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) since you could be depending on user input to a text box.